# Collapse a Pandas multiindex or run OLS regression on a multiindexed dataframe

Tags: python, hierarchical-data, regression, pandas, multi-index

I used pivot to reshape my data and now have a column `multiindex`.  I want the resulting columns to be the X variables in a simple OLS regression.  The Y's are another series with the same row index.

When I try running

```
model1 = ols(y = gdp0, x = MIDAS_small)
```

I get

```
TypeError: can only call with other hierarchical index objects
```

I can imagine two solutions but can't figure out either one:

1. Collapse the multiindex.  Rather than having columns of the form ('before', 'var1') and ('after', 'var1'), I would just have a bunch of 'beforevar1', 'aftervar1', etc.  Then I could use ols to produce a nice and sufficiently legible table.
2. Is there some way to run a regression with a multiindex?  It seems like it was designed in part for this sort of thing, especially panel regressions, but I couldn't find any relevant examples or documentation.

Well, I found an inelegant solution to #1:
I can create a new dataframe, loop over both column indexes, and insert new columns into the new dataframe with the same name, but with names as strings instead of tuples.  There must be a more elegant, single command, right?

Comment: please add an example dataset

Answer (score 1):

Have you tired using dmatricies from Patsy to prepare a regression friendly DataFrame?

An example is located here:

http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/gettingstarted.html

Im sure you are aware of the .unstack() function in pandas that would allow you remove the hierarchical indexing, but it with dmatrices could produce the result that your looking for.